# checking groups at runtime with devise and devise_ldap_authenticatable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ldap

I can get this devise_ldap_authenticatable working just fine when I don't care about what groups they are, it either connects to ldap and authenticates the user signing in under devise or doesn't.  But I want to let only certain members that are apart of one or several specific groups in.  I had a post on this question here:

[Checking group membership in rails devise ldap gem, is it in the yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201053/checking-group-membership-in-rails-devise-ldap-gem-is-it-in-the-yaml)

(the gem for completeness sake is this one: https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable)

Got to thinking I am asking the wrong question.  I think I want to know how in devise (and the  devise_ldap_authenticatable is the data stored where perhaps I can peek at my array of memberOf's myself and check the groups for myself in code, and then at that time don't let them in.  Is there anywhere on the net that's hows this?  My googling has turned up nothing but not being a ldap or devise pro I am guessing my terms suck.
  I am sure I just might of missed the how to do this, closest I can see that might help (Though in its form as I read it makes little sense to me is the part on the readme here:

https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/blob/master/README.md

about querying ldap, is this the case?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with a callback or validation on the `User` (or equivalent) model.

```
before_create :user_is_not_member_of_specified_group?

private

def user_is_not_member_of_specified_group?
  member_of = Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"memberOf")
  test member_of
end
```

where `test` is a method that returns true/false based on your conditions for the member groups.

The `Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"memberOf")` is a method from `devise_ldap_authenticatable` that will return an array of member groups. You'll want to run your group testing on this array.

If you use a validation you could specify an error message for users that failed the test. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Another way to handle this would be to let your gem handle the redirection and error messages by monkeypatching the `authorized?` method in `Devise::LdapAdapter::LdapConnect` (https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/blob/master/lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/ldap_adapter.rb). It would look like:

```
Devise::LdapAdapter::LdapConnect.class_eval do
  def user_group_test
    member_of = self.ldap_param_value("memberOf")
    test member_of # your group test method
  end

  def authorized?
    DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Authorizing user #{dn}")
    if !user_group_test
      DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Not authorized because custom authentication failed.")
      return false
    elsif !authenticated?
      DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Not authorized because not authenticated.")
      return false
    elsif !in_required_groups?
      DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Not authorized because not in required groups.")
      return false
    elsif !has_required_attribute?
      DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Not authorized because does not have required attribute.")
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end

end
```

You would want to put this in a custom initializer file in `config/initializers`.

Comment: I am still learning the finer bits of rails and ruby.  Is what you wrote there a helper?

Comment: No, it's just a custom [ActiveRecord callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). You can read more about them here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html. It is a method, but `helpers` in Rails usually refers to `view` helper methods.

Comment: Ahh so this method lives in the User.rb model and the callback is defined before_create and then I can run that method which basically checks the groups for me and gives it a thumbs up or down if the user should be created in the User table of the devise database piece yah?

Comment: Correct. Rails will call `user_is_not_member_of_specified_group?` before it saves the new user; if this method returns `false` it will prevent the user from being created. However, this will display a nasty error message to the user. You'll probably want to use validation or a `Devise` exception to let the user know what went wrong and what they should do next.

Comment: I just also wanted to clarify, I am guessing the Devise exception is due to the fact its assuming the user is in the user table and they are not because of that user_is_not_member returning false bit and so devise has a hissy fit?

Comment: Yes, you can raise a `Devise` exception from the callback. I've put another alternative solution in my answer which lets your gem handle the error messages and redirection.

Comment: ty again for this, I should open another ticket but perhaps I can quickly get this answered.  I am not a rails magician as I found out by puzzling over how that code works once in the config/initializers folder (put it in a file called customdevisecheck.rb)in either case I can return true and false and it works though the troubling thing is, the error is the same "Invalid email or password" is flashed on the login page, I would like to flash my own message,i am not sure where to do this perhaps a config file somewhere?  or am i stuck with that as an error no matter the true reason for failure?

Comment: The quick answer is yes, you can customize this, by overriding the Devise flash message in your `config/locales/en.yml`. You'll probably need to override `en: devise: failure: invalid`. See here for more information: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#i18n.

Comment: Indeed I found the file, and if I read the github link right I can customize in the file but it looks like I cannot add my own "not_in_group" or something.  Still investigating, if I wanted it seems like I would have to hack the gem to recognize this somehow and it would go beyond the scope of that config/intializers

Comment: Yes, the gem `devise_ldap_authenticatable` only provides a generic fail warning. Relevant code is in `authenticate_with_ldap` here: https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/blob/master/lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/model.rb and in `authenticate!` here: https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/blob/master/lib/devise_ldap_authenticatable/strategy.rb. If you need a custom message, you might need to tap into `Devise` higher up the line (or use something like my initial suggestion).