# assigning roles in devise/cancan/deviseldap/rolify and using ldap_param_value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ldap, cancan

Bottom line up front:
   How can I assign a role from ldap right away when a user logs in.

I am using devise/cancan/deviseldap/rolify to authenticate users and then hopefully assign a role.  I am close *i think* to getting this working.   What I have is a custom initializer that lets the user into the app only if they have a certain memberOf in their ldap entry.

this works thanks to the gracious help from the person in this thread:

[checking groups at runtime with devise and devise_ldap_authenticatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257728/checking-groups-at-runtime-with-devise-and-devise-ldap-authenticatable/17281314?noredirect=1#comment25534199_17281314)

So now it is time for me to assign roles, after trolling around on the net I figured maybe the best way was the after_create in user.rb from devise.  I had these memberOf's in the config/initializer but cannot get access to them later like in the `user.rb` as described by the following what I attempted in the `user.rb`:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     after_create :assign_role
     ...
     ...
  private
  def assign_role
   puts "Assigning role!"
   member_of = self.ldap_param_value("memberOf")  #get array #i know self here is wrong
   member_of.each do |str|
   if str.include? 'Help Desk Admin'
      self.roles << "admin"
   end
   if str.include? 'Password Manager'
      self.roles << "password_manager"
   end
   if str.include? 'Security'
     self.roles << "security"
   end
   if str.include? 'Help Desk'
     self.roles << "help_desk"
   end
  end

 puts "roles assigned!"
 self.update
end
```

The biggest problem (there are many I am still a ruby noobie) is that i have that call to a method ldap_param_value and I know calling it on self is not correct, I got this code working same line in the config/initializer/customdevise.rb (this is for my front gate catch all check): (I know i need the right object instantiated to get access to the ldap_param_value above, but not sure what it is).  I thought the self was: Devise::LdapAdapter, but I tried that above and it still didn't work:

`Devise::LdapAdapter.ldap_param_value(...)`

For completeness my `config/initializer/customedevise.rb`

```
Devise::LdapAdapter::LdapConnect.class_eval do
  def user_group_test
  member_of = self.ldap_param_value("memberOf") #self works here...
  checkgroups member_of # your group test method  end

 def checkgroups(members)
  retVal = false
  members.each do |str|
    if str.include? 'Help Desk Admin' or str.include? 'Password Manager' or  str.include? 'Security' or str.include? 'Help Desk'
        retVal = true;
    end
  end
  return retVal
end
#    'CN=Password Manager'
#    'CN=Help Desk'
#    'CN=Help Desk Admin'
#    'CN=Security'


def authorized?
DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Authorizing user #{dn}")
  if !user_group_test
    DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Not authorized because custom authentication failed.")
    return false
  elsif !authenticated?
    DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Not authorized because not authenticated.")
    return false
  elsif !in_required_groups?
    DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Not authorized because not in required groups.")
    return false
  elsif !has_required_attribute?
    DeviseLdapAuthenticatable::Logger.send("Not authorized because does not have required attribute.")
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
 end
end
```

Note: Another flaw above is that devise does not know exactly why the authentication failed... I suffer with that and changed the `devise.en.yml` files `invalid:` to include more information:

```
en:
  devise:
   confirmations:
    confirmed: "Your account was successfully confirmed. You are now signed in."
    send_instructions: "You will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes."
    send_paranoid_instructions: "If your email address exists in our database, you will receive an email with instructions about how to confirm your account in a few minutes."
   failure:
     already_authenticated: "You are already signed in."
     inactive: "Your account was not activated yet."
     invalid: "Invalid email or password.  Or not a member of the correct group"

      ..etc...
```

Comment: I can understand what you are trying to do. But I dont get how/why you are using LDAP here.

Comment: because we are authenticating against ldap and the roles are stored in ldap.  Active directory to be more specific.

Comment: Great... I stored my roles in a mysql table. I will share with the code that does it. The difference between you and me should be the role retrieval mechanisms then. Care to explain why roles are stored in LDAP?

Comment: Well I think the role retrieval mechanisms are almost key here.  Though the roles are there because what I am building is a site to replace an older site...this older site did everything in AD.  So the users have access to the new site, I want it to be transparent: they login and their roles transfer over.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple,

1. A table Permissions will have all the models and actions that could be performed by users.
2. Permissions HABTM Users and Users HABTM Permissions
3. Roles has_many Users, User belongs_to Role
4. Roles HABTM Permissions and Permissions HABTM Roles
5. If you establish all the above associations and based on the current_user id, you can retrieve whats the role of the User and retrieve their Permissions and those permissions will be instantiated in Ability class by the following method,

   ```
        def initialize(user)   
           user.role.permissions.each do |permission|
             if permission.subject_class == "all"
               can permission.action.to_sym, permission.subject_class.to_sym
             else
               can permission.action.to_sym, permission.subject_class.constantize
           end
         end
        end
   ```

This link shows how to do it,

http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2012/10/23/dynamic-roles-and-permissions-using-cancan/

Comment: wow lots of stuff there.  I really think I just need to be able to get the ldap roles and then save them to the database.  Whilst making sure my application.yml has the roles set up there that I am saving to the database (after reading and testing against what was found in ldap) and I planned on doing this during user create...my biggest issue is just not having access to the roles from ldap during after_create

Comment: I upvoted this cause it was a good response but I didn't accept as an answer because it didn't get to the crux of what my particular issue was getting the memberOf out of ldap in somewhere that was NOT the config/initializers.